# Item views: setSelectionModel and support for row editing

Tags: c++, qt

In my Qt (6.3.1) application, for a model I developed, I noticed the `submit()` method being called all the time.
After some debugging, I noticed, in `void QTableView::setSelectionModel`/`QTreeView::setSelectionModel`, this:

```
    if (d->selectionModel) {
        // support row editing
        connect(d->selectionModel, SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),
                d->model, SLOT(submit()));
    }
```

The documentation for `QAbstractItemModel::submit()` mentions *"this function is typically used for row editing"*, which means this is done on purpose.

I have got more than 1 problem with this way of doing things, compared to the alternative of letting/requiring application developers to create the connection themselves:

- Views do not seem to have a property to stop this connection from being created, hence the behavior is more than just a default, it is mandatory.
- I do not see any way to know what to do except looking through Qt's source code. I had rather have to create the connection myself if I want it.
- Only `QSqlTableModel` seems to have a mechanism to handle this (`editStrategy()`) but I could find nothing in neither `QAbstractItemModel` nor `QAbstractTableModel`.

-> what would be a good reason to want this connection above to be **always** created?
 Or am I perhaps wrong thinking this design is a bad one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after 4 weeks without another answer nor any comment.

Despite having found a solution that seems to work in every case (see below), I still think this very design choice made by Qt as well as other special case they implemented are bad choices, would be interested to read other opinions in the comments.

---

Better than disconnecting signals, the solution I ended up implementing was to subclass `QIdentityProxyModel` and create an attribute to block the calls to `submit` (+ optionally `revert`).

```
void MyModel::revert() {
    if (forwardRevertCalls)
        QIdentityProxyModel::revert();
}
bool MyModel::submit() {
    if (forwardSubmitCalls)
        return QIdentityProxyModel::submit();
    else
        return false;
}
```

The reason for this choice is because of another special case in `QStyledItemDelegate::eventFilter`. Found in the documentation:

> If the editor's type is QTextEdit or QPlainTextEdit then Enter and Return keys are not handled.

And I suppose things like `QSpinBox` do not behave this way.

This was causing `submit` to be called whenever I pressed Enter to validate an input in my model and change the selected row in 1 input; more precisely, it would execute `case QAbstractItemDelegate::SubmitModelCache` in `QAbstractItemView::closeEditor`.